# issue with exposing ports using docker compose

Tags: docker

`docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -v $(pwd):/src budotemplate_app node server.js` works but `docker-compse run app node server.js` doesn't show anything in the browser.  any ideas?

https://github.com/oren/budo-template/blob/af0681a3b8af4d6f4ca16d4a371f775261986476/docker-compose.yml

docker-compose.yml

```
app:
  build: .
  volumes:
   - .:/src
  ports:
   - "3000:3000"
  expose:
   - "3000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:edge
RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories 
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --update iojs && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
WORKDIR /src
COPY . /src
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`run` command in docker-compose is different than docker.
If you want the ports to be exposed you have to use `--service-ports`.

This is the complete command: `docker-compse run --service-ports app node server.js`